# google adsense - non-english website

Tags: adsense

Good day all.
I created a website which has 90% non-english contents/text (Urdu-Pakistan). Is my website eligible for Google Adsense? Website (`www.urdutweet.com`) URLs are english like `http://www.urdutweet.com/all-tweets/`

In Google Analytics I set my Target Country to Pakistan, do I need to set `hreflang` attribute in links? Do I have to wait for specific time period before apply like few months? Please guide me for getting Google Adsense approved status. Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. It **might** be on topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdSense supports publishers in several different languages. But Urdu is not among them

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9727?hl=en

Quote:
*Please also be aware that placing the AdSense code on pages with content primarily in an unsupported language is not permitted by the AdSense program policies.*

Comment: Thanks for reply. there are many websites with un-supported language having AdSense program. Your views on it please?

Comment: Urdu is supported now.